# How to initialise classes that contain methods in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am very new to Typescript. I just started learning it seven days ago. I've come across classes and interfaces and so I have this simple class:

```
class Rectangle{
    height: number;
    width: number;

    /**
     *
     */
    constructor(height: number, width: number) {
        this.height = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    getArea(height: number, width: number): number{
        return height * width;
    }
}
```

And tried to instantiate the class like this: (I'm following a tutorial from Youtube)

```
let [item1, item2]: Rectangle[] = [
    {height: 10, width: 10},
    {height: 11, width: 15}
];
```

When I compiled it, it produced an error:

> Product.ts:65:5 - error TS2741: Property 'getArea' is missing in type '{ height: number; width: number; }' but required in type 'Rectangle'.

> 65     {height: 10, width: 10}
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> Classes.ts:29:5
> 29     getArea(height: number, width: number): number{
> ~~~~~~~
> 'getArea' is declared here.

> Found 1 error in Product.ts:65

From what I understood so far is, the array initialisation is like "here's two Rectangles with the following dimensions". But somehow, the compiler is expecting I include the getArea() method as well which is confusing and tbh, quite new to me (and doesn't make sense).

If I remove the getArea() method from the class definition, the code compiles. Coming from C#, this is not what I'm used to and I expected the object initialisation to be correct and compile successfully.

Please eli5 me why this won't compile? I just started dabbling with Typescript since 7 days ago, and this is a massive headscratcher.

Comment: `From what I understood so far is, the array initialisation is like "here's two Rectangles with the following dimensions"` No, you initialized the array with two objects with `width` and `height` and TS basically complains *"but you told me this array contains Rectangles, your objects are missing this `getArea` method here ..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ height: 10, width: 10 }
```

This is what's called an "object literal". It is a very convenient way to create objects, and in fact i'd say it's the way i create objects about 95% of the time. But it will only have the exact properties that you specify on this line of code<sup>1</sup>. So this just has a `.height` and a `.width`; it has no `.getArea` property.

> From what I understood so far is, the array initialisation is like "here's two Rectangles with the following dimensions"

I would describe it as "here's two objects, I want to treat them as Rectangles", and typescript says "you can't do that, because they don't have all the properties Rectangles do." To get that extra `.getArea` property you'll want to create instances of the Rectangle class, not use object literals.

Javascript/Typescript classes are similar to C# classes<sup>2</sup>, allowing you to define a blueprint for an object. The class defines what data the object has, and a set of methods to work on that data. You can then use the `new` keyword to create an instance of this class, and it will inherit the methods that you've defined for it

```
constructor(height: number, width: number) {
```

This is the constructor of the class, and you can see it requires two things to be passed in: a width, and a height. So the way that you create instances of `Rectangle` is:

```
let [item1, item2]: Rectangle[] = [
    new Rectangle(10, 10),
    new Rectangle(11, 15)
];
```

And if you like, you can leave off the type on the left hand side, since typescript can tell it's a `Rectangle[]` from the right hand side:

```
let [item1, item2] = [
    new Rectangle(10, 10),
    new Rectangle(11, 15)
];
```

---

<sup>1) The object will inherit a few properties which all objects have, such as `.toString`

2) Similar in terms of their purpose, not how they are implemented</sup>

Comment: as an extra, it is completely unnecessary to specify the type of that declaration - TypeScript is smart enough to infer that both `item1` and `item2` will be `Rectangle`.